# TreeSet list of <Employe> order the list and show people from list with specific properties

Tags: java, treeset

I have a list of Employee (Employee is a class). Employee has 3 properties

```
private String name    
private int yearsSpentInCompany
private boolean parkingSpace
```

and has the constructor of these properties

```
 public Employee(String name, int yearsSpentInCompany, boolean parkingSpace) {
        this.name = name;
        this.yearsSpentInCompany = yearsSpentInCompany;
        this.parkingSpace = parkingSpace;}
```

The list is this

```
List<Employee> allEmployeesOfCompany = new ArrayList<Employee>();
```

So i have in the list for example 10 employees. How can i obtain a list of employees who don't have any parking spaces (parkingSpace = false), and the same list ordered based on years spent in company.

My incomplete sollution: i defined my own comparator for years spent in company

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class YearsComp implements Comparator<Employee> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
        if (o1.getYearsSpentInCompany() > o2.getYearsSpentInCompany()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

**The Output is**

```
=== Employees sorted by seniority in work === 
Employee: Vlad === YearsSpentInCompany: 1 === ParkingPlace:true
Employee: Ayian === YearsSpentInCompany: 2 === ParkingPlace:true
Employee: Ion === YearsSpentInCompany: 2 === ParkingPlace:true
Employee: Victor === YearsSpentInCompany: 2 === ParkingPlace:false
Employee: Aurel === YearsSpentInCompany: 8 === ParkingPlace:false
Employee: Tudod === YearsSpentInCompany: 10 === ParkingPlace:true
Employee: Sebi === YearsSpentInCompany: 13 === ParkingPlace:true
Employee: Marcel === YearsSpentInCompany: 15 === ParkingPlace:false
Employee: Raul === YearsSpentInCompany: 16 === ParkingPlace:true
Employee: Andrei === YearsSpentInCompany: 17 === ParkingPlace:false
```

the sort is good.
 Emplyee class implements Comparable and i Ovveride in this class:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
        if( this.parkingSpace == false)
            System.out.println("No parking place: " + this.getName());
        return 0;
    }
```

**The Output is**

```
No parking place: Marcel  ---15 years
No parking place: Aurel   ---- 8 years
No parking place: Victor   ---- 2 years
No parking place: Andrei    --- 17 years
```

Which is partially correct because i want to sort the employee with out parking space in order of their years spent in company like this

```
No parking place: Victor   ---- 2 years
No parking place: Aurel   ---- 8 years
No parking place: Marcel  ---15 years
No parking place: Andrei    --- 17 years
```

How can i combine these 2 methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A solution without using Streams:**

```
    List<Employee> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
    for(Employee e : allEmployeesOfCompany) {
        if(!e.parkingSpace)
            filteredList.add(e);
    }

    Collections.sort(filteredList, new YearsComp());
```

**A solution using Streams:**

```
    YearsComp yearsComparator = new YearsComp();
    List<Employee> filteredAndSortedList = allEmployeesOfCompany.stream()
            .filter(e -> !e.parkingSpace)
            .sorted(yearsComparator)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Side Note:**

your comparison method should return 0 if the 2 employees have the same number of years. And you don't need to implement Comparable if you do the comparison here in the YearsComp.

```
public class YearsComp implements Comparator<Employee> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee o1, Employee o2) {
        int returnValue = 0;
        if (o1.getYearsSpentInCompany() > o2.getYearsSpentInCompany()) {
            returnValue = 1;
        } else if (o1.getYearsSpentInCompany() < o2.getYearsSpentInCompany()) {
            returnValue = -1;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

I think it is better to have a separate Comparator and to not implement Comparable in this case, because if you need a different comparison later on, you could make an other Comparator, but if you go with implementing Comparable then you can only have 1 comparison.

Comment: @ Bentaye Thank you for you're advice and for the solutions, they work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Using `compareTo` to get the employees without a parking lot makes no sense. `compareTo` should be using for ordering (and uniqueness test in `TreeSet`), not for filtering.

You can easily filter and sort with Java 8 `Stream`s:

```
List<Employee> output =
    allEmployeesOfCompany.stream()
                         .filter(emp -> !emp.parkingSpace)
                         .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(Employee::getYearsSpentInCompany))
                         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I never heard of Stream S yet, i follow a java course (3 months old only) and we never talked about it.  We are at object cointainers. You`re code works fine, i dont understand it yet, but i will read the documentation.

Comment: @Mezzadri Well, without using Streams, you can create a new ArrayList, iterate over the elements of the original list to obtain only the Employees having no parking space, add them to the new list, and finally sort that list using your `YearsComp` comparator (with Collections.sort).

Comment: @ Eran Thank you, i managed to get it done with you're second advice too.